# iPhone: image/advertisment above the navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Our application currently looks like this:

```
[ Navigation Controller]
[       Content        ]
[  Tab Bar Controller  ]
```

What we want to do now is to add advertising to the free version, which we would like to put on top of the Navigation Controller, like this:

```
[     Advertisment     ]
[ Navigation Controller]
[       Content        ]
[  Tab Bar Controller  ]
```

So I'm wondering if this is possible and if so, if it would be accepted by Apple for the App Store??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same for my application. What I did was the following:

In my window I add 2 subviews.

- One with the advertisement.
- One with the navigation controller.

This works for me and the advertisements stay on the screen will the user navigates. 
I created this in the last few days and I'm going to submit this to Apple somewhere in the next few days. But I don't see any reason why they could have a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to subclass the navigation controller. Have a look at this link [Apple's Docs on Nav Controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to understand how the view is overlayed. Subclassing or modifying the frame of the nav bar is the neatest way to accomplish this in my opinion.